# How to add Keycloak to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, keycloak

I'm trying to add https://github.com/robsontenorio/laravel-keycloak-guard  to my project,

I added a route under the auth:api middleware after installing the above library. but when I go to it I get an "Unauthenticated." error.

```
    Route::group(["middleware" => "auth:api"], function () {
        Route::get('test', [AuthController::class, 'test']);
    });
```

```
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        dd(Auth::token());
    }
```

And below is an image showing the exception

[image]

The request has an Authorization header of a keycloak access token

[image]

I made sure I change my auth guards in `config/auth.php` like so:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'api',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'keycloak',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ]
    ],
```

this is my .env file

```
KC_CLIENT_SECRET=08Ztom3XOnaz7FhVryMFh1DfOKx99gGX
KEYCLOAK_REALM_PUBLIC_KEY=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAufJuaG1oZ/b7MVmu7npwULXCvLig/a4426kho6ZWEttQIfguXYtruvYJBaA6Sxpd+c8YkHHg21O6/ugdbjaRHCOipGvTAPwPaugY6q9H8pw8rgF4JG+lpD/u9TZqZaMegoSQDVrnkVYRctJELC+DJFkQi/u/DB3BOq6wzUHsLjDCHWdMfk8W3FV0AzlIpze5MBndxbYmE/n3JqiyftGToyQrCEDy7HTjp1rrrJf5rJSLU2QgEdDSBNplZhMUZHq2Ah3j119AdluRlIYd4K/iL68bG+CweqYVewdK1NSEi7xhinSliSbpzZudFblQ2AGPjbj3VRP2FeMwKD/4spwCMQIDAQAB
KEYCLOAK_LOAD_USER_FROM_DATABASE=true
KEYCLOAK_ALLOWED_RESOURCES=account
KEYCLOAK_IGNORE_RESOURCES_VALIDATION=false
KEYCLOAK_APPEND_DECODED_TOKEN=true
```

and I do have the default config/keycloak.php file

```
<?php

return [
    'realm_public_key' => env('KEYCLOAK_REALM_PUBLIC_KEY', null),

    'load_user_from_database' => env('KEYCLOAK_LOAD_USER_FROM_DATABASE', true),

    'user_provider_custom_retrieve_method' => null,

    'user_provider_credential' => env('KEYCLOAK_USER_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL', 'username'),

    'token_principal_attribute' => env('KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_PRINCIPAL_ATTRIBUTE', 'preferred_username'),

    'append_decoded_token' => env('KEYCLOAK_APPEND_DECODED_TOKEN', false),

    'allowed_resources' => env('KEYCLOAK_ALLOWED_RESOURCES', null),

    'ignore_resources_validation' => env('KEYCLOAK_IGNORE_RESOURCES_VALIDATION', false),

    'leeway' => env('KEYCLOAK_LEEWAY', 0),

    'input_key' => env('KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_INPUT_KEY', null)
];
```

What should I do to get the test method to return the correct token?

Answer (score 0):

turns out the modheader extension removed my tab filter on it's own so it wasn't sending the Authorization header, solved!